# Best practies for handle exception in repository layer

Tags: spring, exception, handle

I use spring and hibernate together. Application has repository, service, controller layer. In controller, I handle exceptions using @ExceptionHandler. What would be the right way for handling exceptions in repository layer(DAO or CRUD )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think it is required to catch any exceptions in repository classes, they should rather be allowed propagate to controllers so that appropriate message could be displayed to user.
for handling general type of exceptions spring 3.2 has added `@ControllerAdvice` which is good place to handle exceptions, please refer to spring-reference for details.
If you still want to handle exceptions in repository classes please mention the scenario.